# Scheme theoretic 'class inclusions'

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

For lack of a better name*, I call the following two things class inclusions:
$$1) \quad\textbf{Magma}\supset \textbf{Semigroup}\supset\textbf{Monoid}\supset \textbf{Group}\supset \textbf{Abelian Group}$$

$$2)\quad \textbf{Commutative Rings}\supset \textbf{IDs}\supset \textbf{GCD domains}\supset \textbf{UFDs}\supset\textbf{PIDs}\supset \textbf{EDs}\supset\textbf{Fields}$$

---

Looking in the index of Hartshorne - Algebraic geometry, we see the following words before Scheme: 'Affine', 'Connected', 'Formal', 'geometrically integral', 'geometrically irreducible', 'geometrically reduced', 'integral', 'irreducible', 'locally factorial', 'locally noetherian', 'noetherian', 'nonprojective', 'nonseparated', 'nonsingular in codimension one', 'normal', 'of finite type over a field', 'reduced', 'regular' and 'separate.

Is there some notion of a class inclusion diagram here? Where can I find one if so?

---

*And the latter is called this on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Konrad Voelkel](http://www.konradvoelkel.com) licensed his [nice diagram](http://www.konradvoelkel.com/2011/11/properties-of-scheme-morphisms/) under the same [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license as this site, so we can luckily embed it here:

[image: Properties of Scheme Morphisms]

I would also like to add that Bjorn Poonen has nice tables of permanence properties for various types of scheme morphisms in the appendix to [Rational Points on Varieties](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf), although that isn't exactly what you are looking for.

**Edit.** I also realize that Appendices C and D in Görtz–Wedhorn are also very useful.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of inclusions. Here are some of them (the list is not complete) :

$\bullet$ Geometrically integral $\subset$ geometrically irreducible $\subset$ irreducible

$\bullet$ Geometrically integral $\subset$ geometrically reduced $\subset$ reduced

$\bullet$ Geometrically integral $\subset$ integral $\subset$ irreducible $\subset$ connected

$\bullet$ Regular $\subset$ locally factorial $\subset$ normal (provided that you call a scheme "normal" if all its local rings are integrally closed, but do not require the scheme to be integral) $\subset$ reduced

$\bullet$ Projective over $k$ $\subset$ of finite type over $k$ $\subset$ Noetherian $\subset$ locally Noetherian

$\bullet$ Affine $\subset$ separated $\subset$ quasi-separated

All those inclusions can be found in classical books about schemes (Hartshorne, EGA, Liu, Görtz-Wedhorn, etc), but you probably have to look for them one by one.

Comment: Thank you for that. This will help me very much.